# Render json string from controller to mvc view

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

My json string is coming as follows:

```
"[{\"StartTime\":\"09:00\",\"Dates\":\"05-28-2015\",\"Code\":\"DF\",\"LocationCode\":\"NY\"},{\"StartTime\":\"09:30\",\"Dates\":\"05-28-2015\",\"Code\":\"DF\",\"LocationCode\":\"NY\"},{\"StartTime\":\"10:00\",\"Dates\":\"05-28-2015\",\"Code\":\"DF\",\"LocationCode\":\"NY\"},{\"StartTime\":\"10:30\",\"Dates\":\"05-28-2015\",\"Code\":\"DF\",\"LocationCode\":\"NY\"},{\"StartTime\":\"11:30\",\"Dates\":\"05-28-2015\",\"Code\":\"DF\",\"LocationCode\":\"NY\"}]"
```

I need to parse this json string on view and show the data in a table.
I am new to json. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

```
$("#divLoad").load("GetAvailableTimeSlots?strProvider=" + provider + "&strFrom=" + from, function (data) {
            var newStr = data.replace('"[', '').replace(']"', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '');
            var dataArr = newStr.split('},{');
            var jsonArr = new Array(dataArr.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
                dataArr[i] = '{' + dataArr[i] + '}';
                var dataElem = dataArr[i].replace('{{', '{').replace('}}', '}');
                var jsonElem = "'" + dataElem + "'";
                jsonArr[i] = JSON.parse(jsonElem);

            }

            $(this).html(jsonArr);
        });
```

Comment: … show the data in a *what*? – You should provide some code showing what you tried so far.

Comment: I want to show data in a table.

Comment: I tried the above code to just show the value in a div. Code gives error at 'JSON.parse(jsonElem)' : Unexpected token '.
On debugging the js, jsonElem is coming within double quotes, hence the error.

Comment: Just call `JSON.parse(data)` and manipulate the javascript object instead of doing string manipulation -- It will be less error prone and you won't get errors like the one in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the jQuery.parseJSON() method.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 0):

Just call `JSON.parse(data)` and manipulate the javascript object instead of performing error-prone string manipulation.

```
function (data) {
    var locations = JSON.parse(data);
    var table = $("<ul>");
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var row = $("<li>").text(locations[i].StartTime + " " + locations[i].Dates + " " ...);
        table.append(row);
    }
    $("#divLoad").empty().append(table);  // $(this) won't work
}
```

This example is using an unordered list but you can easily replace this with table markup.

Here's what it looks like in Chrome dev tools with `console.log(locations)` after parsing:

[image: console.log(locations)]

Comment: I am not getting any result in locations. 
var locations = JSON.parse(data); I think JSON.parse(data) is not parsing the data

Comment: I took your string from your post `"[{\"StartTime\":\"09:00\", ...` and used it in place of `data` and it parsed correctly. Does it throw an error when you try to parse?

Comment: I got it. I am getting the data. Thanks a lot.